# Why my protocol in swift doesn't works?

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2, protocols

I am trying to call my function in ViewController from Button class using protocol but it doesn't works. Basically I subclassing my button and use `override func touchesBegan` . When I touch my button it works and it says "***touchesBegan from UIButton Subsclass***" But the problem is why `func didTapOnItem` that I putted on view controller doesn't react at all? here is my code:

```
protocol AnimationProtocol {
    func didTapOnItem(touches: Set<UITouch>)
}
class Buttons: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    @IBInspectable var isAddButton: Bool = true

    var delegate: AnimationProtocol?

    let effectTwo = ButtonEffectTwo(frame: CGRectZero)

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
        fillColor.setFill()
        path.fill()

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touchesBegan from UIButton Subsclass")
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        self.delegate?.didTapOnItem(touches)


    }


}
```

This function below I putted on my ViewController class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AnimationProtocol {
      func didTapOnItem(touches: Set<UITouch>) {
                print("touchesBegan from didtap")

                view.addSubview(effectTwo)
            }
}
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: are you sure the delegate isnt nil?

Comment: @Fonix I am not sure to be honest I did this kind of method on my previous project and it just fine but now doesn't seem to be works

Comment: Learn to use the debugger.

Comment: I did and It just blank @trojanfoe

Comment: "blank"?  What's blank?

Comment: there is no warning at all@trojanfoe

Comment: Where you set the delegate?

Comment: put a breakpoint on the line `self.delegate?.didTapOnItem(touches)` and see if the delegate is nil in the inspector

Comment: @Fonix I did and it says ' touches (Set<UITouch>) [0] '

Comment: @elio.d on ViewController

Comment: @Fonix I think you are right the delegate is nil, how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you show us how you declare and assign the delegate in your view controller?

Comment: Look code above @elio.d

Comment: @hdjkshdak thats totally up to you really, you just need to assign it somewhere, possibly when your `ViewController` class is created

Comment: @hdjkshdak in the code you posted is missing the part where you say that your view controller is the delegate, and that is the code I asked you to show... are you following me?